# Controling the size of a Portlet in Liferay

Tags: java, layout, liferay, vaadin

I have a simple Vaadin portlet which displays an Embedded page e.g  www.stackoverflow..com. In Liferay I set the page layout where the portlet is to 1 column Layout so that the portlet fills out the full page. Now if I resize my browser (Firefox 11) the portlet is not being effected at all.  Is there a way to make my Portlet resize itself if I resize my Browser ? I checked the ?debug console  there are no layout errors and if I resize my broswer vaadin seems to call some resize funktions to set the new height, Width

```
Running layout functions due to window resize
New window width: 1265
New window height: 906
```

but nothing happens.

Im working with vaadin 6.6.6 and liferay 6.1

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia take a look at this thread : https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/433164 its not an actual solution of the problem , but a good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look at Iframe portlet which is in Liferay. This portlet uses javascript to resize itself and does basically what you want to achieve.

Comment: I dont think that I can add an portlet within a portlet , my portlet has an Edit mode and so on

Comment: I didn't mean to use IFrame portlet. Just take a look at its source code and get the inspiration how to achieve what you need.