# gwt rootpanel to portlet

Tags: gwt, portlet

In gwt, I set the hosted page html height=100% and body height = 100% and then in entrypoint Class, I set rootpanel height = 100% and width = 100% and the enclosing docklayoutpanel height = 100% and width = 100%.
but in portlet view.jsp, as it is only a fragment of whole page, so it has no  and  element, so how to migrate this setting to portlent (liferay portal protlet)

Comment: thanks for your remind, I forget to tick the upper, lower or tick symbols previously

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I've written a small entry in my blog about *including a GWT portlet inside a Liferay portlet*.

If you follow the steps I've describe, you just need to set the docklayoutpanel sizes to 100%.

http://www.jmichelgarcia.com/2012/gwt-smartgwt-in-a-liferay-portlet/

**EDIT**

Regarding the sizing issues, I didn't find a nice solution. However, you can use GWT to retrieve the screen sizes at runtime if it helps.

As far as I know, Liferay's portlet policy is to size based on its contents.

Please see : [Controling the size of a Portlet in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205786/controling-the-size-of-a-portlet-in-liferay)

this : https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/433164

and this : http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10327941

Comment: I use GWT without smartGWT, when I try to 'code'RootPanel.get("myApplicationDIV").add("MyOutermostLayoutManager");'code'
and set MyOutermostLayoutManager width and height to 100%, in liferay portal, the div does not shown. any help?
@Jean-Michel

Comment: Using SmartGWT is not mandatory. Please update your question with more information. Code, html contents after loading, etc.

Comment: I found I must set explicit size in the outermost layoutpanel inside rootpanel, like
>MyOutermostLayoutManager.setSize("1000px", "1000px");
but cannot use relative size like percentage
>MyOutermostLayoutManager.setSize("100%", "100%");
but set explicit size is not normal because each screen has different resolution... how to solve this problem in gwt integrate with Liferay Portal.
@Jean-Michel

Comment: after seeing the link you provided, especially from the liferay community, I feel no other choice except setting fixed width and fixed height on rootpanel.
and I think this will lead to problem for different users with different screen size (PC, notebook, netbook......).